# A Boolean'ian Quandary

Tags: java, boolean

Consider the following Java method:

```
public Boolean compare(String val1, String val2) {
    return val1.length() > 0 && val1.equals(val2);
}
```

If it isn't obvious, this method first checks if val1 length is greater than 0 (ie. do we have  something to compare) and then applies an .equal() method.

Of course, the quandary comes about because if val1.length() isn't greater than zero, the method will return a false. Bad because it becomes unknown where the false came from; the val1.length() method or the equals() method.

A rewrite should fix the problem:

```
public Boolean compare(String val1, String val2) {
    if (val1.length() > 0) {
        return val1.equals(val2);
    }
    return // Oh dear.... stuck again !
}
```

The obvious problem here is that Java methods require that a method return the return type specified. In this case I could return true or false (actually, because I've specified Boolean instead of boolean [capital B vs lower B] I can also return a null). So what to return here?  Well it turns out that true or false won't work either, because again if val1.length() is false, whatever my return value is will be what's returned, leading again to a possible false positive or false negative. Although I can set a null here, my calling code will generate a NullPointerException -- so no null.

What I need is not a Boolean, but a TRILEAN!  So, I devised this:

```
// Trilean.java
public enum Trilean {
    FALSE,
    TRUE,
    IGNORE
}
```

And re-wrote my method like so:

```
public Trilean compare(String val1, String val2) {
    if (val1.length() > 0) {
        return (val1.equals(val2)) ? Trilean.TRUE : Trilean.FALSE;
    }
    return Trilean.IGNORE;
}
```

And this works:

```
if (compare(val1, val2) == Trilean.TRUE) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This logic (btw) becomes valid when for example I want to perform regex on a string, say a string that my regex rules demand begin with a Letter or Number, but I only want to run that regex if my string actually isn't empty. Take for example a servlet, were I may have an html input field that is not required. Testing it with these rigid rules "^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$" would cause my val.match() method to return true or false, hence breaking my form field validation, on a non-required field.

So,

```
public Boolean validateField(String data) {
    return data.length() > 0 && data.match("^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$");
}
```

Would generate the same false positives or negatives.

**Question is**: What have been your approaches to quandaries like this?  How can I improve this logic while sticking with Boolean?

Comment: Here's one approach: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Comment: I have always used `enum`s

Comment: So, I'm doing it right?

Comment: @JasonCaldwell Yes. You could use constants aswell, but that is just (the same but) an uglier solution than enums :)

Comment: On a side note: you should normally use the simple type `bool` instead of the object `Boolean`, when you actually need an object they compiler will automatically convert, this is called autoboxing.

Comment: Note that the usual name for this construct is "ternary", as in ternary logic or ternary content-addressable memory (TCAM). The third state is variously referred to as indeterminate, unknown, or "don't care" (especially for netmasks).

Answer (score 0):

Well, my “approach” is the following:

1. Determine how many outcomes of a check I'm interested in
2. Use an appropriate return type

If I only need to act or not to act then `boolean` works fine. If I need three outcomes like act on match, act on not match, and skip then I would often use `Boolean` with `null` signaling the “skip” case. If there are more than 3 outcomes, or I expect their number to change, I'd use an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

The question really is what are you trying to tell? And who is responsible for this.

In your case I would not say `TRUE` and `FALSE` in your result. Because you are asking `compare` (when you ask `isEqual` the case is different). A more natural result options are:

```
public enum CompareResult{
    EQUAL,
    UNEQUAL,
    EMPTY
}
```

Note that I also renamed `Trillian` to the actual type it means, namely the result of a (somewhat special) comparison. If you want to be really precise say: `EQUAL_NON_EMPTY`, this indicates to the users of your function that it isn't your normal comparison, because empty string are treated as a special case. In the same way you should also name your function to indicate it handles empty strings in a different way, for instance `compareStringsIfNotEmpty`. This is a long and clumsy name, which always indicates the function has something special with it.

I could also be that actually the calling function is making a programming mistake when passing an empty string (because it should have validated it's user input). In that case you should be throwing an unchecked exception. 'IllegalArgumentException' is the common type to throw in this case.

Finally if you are interested in this in only a few placed place, it might be possible to limit the scope of this function, because the behaviors is not what someone using might expect.

So all in all: think about the people that will use your function in the future. What do they expect from the name? What might they do wrong if they don't read the documentation properly. How can you avoid these mistakes?

Comment: Just found this: https://code.google.com/p/genson/source/browse/src/main/java/com/owlike/genson/Trilean.java?r=6025ce19a229c479d27278f43c5a9f8ada906b9e